# How do I update a set of duplicate rows in a database, based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of duplicate data, based on multiple columns. I came up with this query to find all the duplicated rows

```
select * 
from polls 
group by server_id, product_id, poll_date 
having count(*) > 1;
```

How do I update these results and set the "updated_by" field to "admin".

I tried doing this, but it doesn't work for me :(

```
update polls 
set updated_by='admin' 
group by server_id, product_id, poll_date 
having count(*) > 1;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: hi. can you give sql code to create your table and insert some sample rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to join your `SELECT` with the `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE `polls` AS `p1`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM `polls`
    GROUP BY `server_id`, `product_id`, `poll_date`
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS `p2`
    ON `p2`.`server_id` = `p1`.`server_id`
    AND `p2`.`product_id` = `p1`.`product_id`
    AND `p2`.`poll_date` = `p1`.`poll_date`
SET `p1`.`updated_by` = 'admin';
```

Of course it would be better to directly join on the primary key (if you have one).

Comment: I get this error: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'updated_by' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Of course we have to specify which table should be used for the update. I updated my answer.

Comment: can you see my question posted below? Thanks

Comment: You should ask a new question.